# Apache 403:Forbidden on sub-directory

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, centos6

CentOS 6.4 64bit, minimal install, in VirtualBox.
Added groupinstall "Development Tools" to install VBox Guest Additions.
Installed Webmin, Apache, MySQL, PHP.

Trying to get a program called "Multicraft" to run. It is downloaded in a .tar.gz file and has an installer that you run. It installed properly but I must visit my.ip/multicraft/install.php to finish install. The folder is located at /var/www/html/multicraft. I keep getting a 403:Forbidden every time I try to access the folder itself or the install.php or index.php file within the folder from a browser. I can reach the main my.ip and it shows the "Apache HTTP Server Test Page"

Apache is run under the apache user and apache group
-I have done a "chown -R apache:apache *" within the /var/www directory to make sure all permissions are correct.
-The installer asks which user to run multicraft in and I made a "minecraft" user and added them to the "apache" group.
-I have added the following into my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file:

```
#user-added directory
<Directory "/var/www/html/multicraft">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

-There are also .htaccess files located within the directory that were installed with the program. Here is a list of all .htaccess files on the system:

```
/root/multicraft/panel/.htaccess
/root/multicraft/panel/protected/.htaccess
/root/multicraft/panel/protected/yii/.htaccess
/root/multicraft/panel/protected/yii/cli/views/webapp/protected/.htaccess
/root/multicraft/panel/protected/yii/cli/views/webapp/themes/classic/views/.htaccess
/root/multicraft/panel/themes/mobile/views/.htaccess
/root/multicraft/panel/themes/simple/views/.htaccess
/var/www/html/multicraft/.htaccess
/var/www/html/multicraft/protected/.htaccess
/var/www/html/multicraft/protected/yii/.htaccess
/var/www/html/multicraft/protected/yii/cli/views/webapp/protected/.htaccess
/var/www/html/multicraft/protected/yii/cli/views/webapp/themes/classic/views/.htaccess
/var/www/html/multicraft/themes/mobile/views/.htaccess
/var/www/html/multicraft/themes/simple/views/.htaccess
```

-Here is the "/var/www/html/multicraft/.htaccess" file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
IndexIgnore */*
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]

# redirect to installer if the request ends with install.php
RewriteRule /install\.php$ install.php [L]

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

I still get this 403:Forbidden on the directory of "/var/www/html/multicraft" access by "my.ip/multicraft" in the browser. I have also tried the "my.ip/multicraft/install.php" and "my.ip/multicraft/index.php" and gotten the same error.

I cannot figure out what I have done wrong. Any ideas on a step I may have missed. Or a configuration I may have screwed up. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does your error logs say?

Comment: Your .htaccess doesn't show a 'forbidden' flag (`[F]`), so that's not likely the cause. `IndexIgnore` seems to only hide files from the autoindex, and not throw a forbidden error either. Use `ls -al` to inspect the rights on each and every file in the multicraft directory. Make sure that Apache has the executable permission on `install.php` and `.htaccess` in the multicraft directory.

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this question, the OP posted it in several forums and received the correct answer (which is to execute `restorecon -r /var/www/html`) here: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6834. There is an explanation of the fix at the link.